# How to read input word by word in FreePascal?

Tags: freepascal

I would like to read from standard input word by word (i.e., the input string is always a collection of words separated with blanks). Now I'm using the `read` function and I read the input char by char.

Is it possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With readln (readline) you can read a whole line that you can split into separate words. There is no function to read words from a file.

Comment: Well you suppose max 256 bytes long input line which is not always my case. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: The functions should be overloaded for dynamic ansistring. Define your strings right and it probably will work with bigger input too.